# About isometric Banach algebra isomorphisms and WAP functionals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $B$ be a Banach algebra and $A\subseteq B$ a subalgebra. It is known that there is a quotient map $\phi: B^*/\textrm{wap}(B)\to A^*/\textrm{wap}(A)$ that is also an $A$-bimodule map.
Let's say only for this post that $A$ is a *large* subalgebra of $B$ (resp. $B$ is a *small* extension of $A$) if $\phi$ is injective. Clearly, $A$ is a large subalgebra of $B$ iff every Hahn-Banach extension of $f\in\textrm{wap}(A)$ to $B$ is a weakly almost periodic functional on $B$.

For the questions, let $A=\ell^1(S)$ for a discrete cancellative semigroup $S$, paired with the predual $c_0(S)$.

> **Q1:** For which classes of $S$,  $B=\textrm{wap}(A)^*$ is a small extension of $A$?

If Q1 is affirmative for some $A=\ell^1(S)$, then

> **Q2:** Does there exist a reflexive Banach space $E$ and a weak$^*$ isometric isomorphism $\pi:A\to B(E)$ such that $B(E)$ is a small extension of $\pi(A)$?